# Make recompiles source files outside project tree every time

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

For some reason make is recompiling the source files that are outside my
project tree every time. I don't normally have such files, but I noticed it while I was testing this Makefile and I would like to understand why. It behaves normally with respect to the source files inside my project tree. Here are my rules. First I have a function

```
src_to_obj = $(basename $(addprefix $(build_dir)/,$(1))).o
```

Then I populate the list of program_objects by calling foreach on the list of sources and applying the above function to each one.

```
$(bin_dir)/$(program_name): $(program_objects)
        $(linker) $(link_flags) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) \
          $^ $(OUTPUT_OPTION)

define build_template =
$$(call src_to_obj,$(1)) : $(1) $$(call dependency_file,$(1))
        // make dependency and build directories
        $$(compile) $$(OUTPUT_OPTION) $$<
        // rename dependency
endef

$(foreach source,$(program_sources),\
  $(eval $(call build_template,$(source))))
```

As I said, this works just fine for the source files in the project directory. For example, the Makefile lives in ~/Projects/foo and most of the source code is in ~/Projects/foo/src. But if I pull in a file A.cc from the home directory,then that file is recompiled every time I run make.

EDIT:
Following Mad-Scientists suggestion, I ran make -d and examined the output. That made the problem clear. Basically, if I feed this a source file ~/bad.cc, then the rule looks like:

```
build/~/bad.o : ~/bad.cc .deps/~/bad.d
        ...
```

However, my script for the rule is creating the file .deps/home/jim/bad.d. Therefore, every time I run make the dependency file is "not there" and the object file has to be remade. I am using the exact same expressions to refer to the file name in the script. However I am guessing that the shell is expanding the ~ to /home/jim. So somehow I have to escape the ~ in the recipe. Thanks to Mad Scientist for pointing out the -d option for make.

I don't have time to make a short self contained correct example right now, but if I can't solve this problem I will come up with one and post it here later.

EDIT EDIT:
So I solved the problem with the following hack:

```
program_sources = $(shell echo $(program_sources))
```

This pre-expands all names so that they are never different in the shell.

Comment: Run make with the `-d` option (redirect the output to a file because it will be very long) then go look at what make tells you about why it decided to rebuild things.  You've not given us anywhere near enough information to help you: most of the variables and functions you're using here are not visible so we have no idea what actual rules are created by these functions.  If you can create a SSCCE we can look at it.

Comment: I didn't want to post the whole Makefile to spare people the trouble of looking through a lot of chaff. Thanks for that tip! I'm looking over the make -d output right now. It might have something to do with the ~ being expanded some places but not others. If I can tell what the problem was I'll post it. If I can't I will post more information to my question.

Comment: @MadScientist If you mention make -d in an answer I will accept it since it made the problem crystal clear.